# Grunt release : Warning: Task "release" not found and it shows "aborted due to warnings"

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-cli

Grunt release : Warning: Task "release" not found and shows aborted due to warnings.

But it shows hint like "Use --force to continue". If i use "--force" to the command it is working fine. What's happening when i use --force before and after.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that all the dependencies for your project are properly installed by running `npm install`.  If there's errors, update your question with that information.

If that does not resolve the problem, check `package.json` for the `grunt-release` plugin.  It will be found under `dependencies` or `devDependencies`.  If it's missing from package.json, run `npm install grunt-release --save-dev` to install the plugin and save it to your project dependencies.

If any errors occur while attempting to resolve your problem this way, update your question and include that information.